# String Mutation JSON Formatter corretly post data

Tags: json

I want to remove the spaces to convert to common post date
As I already used the website https://jsonformatter.org/glimmer-formatter to format the post without spaces, it was left without spaces in the line, but it returned an error

{"query":"mutation submitCommand($params: SubmitCommandInput!) {\n  submitCommand(params: $params) {\n    object {\n      command {\n        id\n        address\n        city\n        corporationName\n        country\n        source\n        discountAmount\n        discountId\n        eligibleAmount\n        email\n        firstName\n        isCorporate\n        lastName\n        paymentMethod\n        postalCode\n        productsAmount\n        region\n        tipAmount\n        totalAmount\n        createdAtUtc\n        eTicketUrl\n        currency\n        extraDonation\n        formId\n        formLang\n        formType\n        locale\n        organizationCountry\n        status\n        transactions {\n          id\n          __typename\n        }\n        __typename\n      }\n      nextAction {\n        type\n        redirectToUrl {\n          returnUrl\n          url\n          __typename\n        }\n        paymentIntentSecret\n        __typename\n      }\n      __typename\n    }\n    error {\n      code\n      message\n      data {\n        fullRates {\n          id\n          remainingTickets\n          __typename\n        }\n        fullChoices {\n          id\n          remainingAnswers\n          __typename\n        }\n        remainingTicketingSeats\n        __typename\n      }\n      __typename\n    }\n    __typename\n  }\n}\n"}
-=-==--=-=-=-==--==--==--=Original-=-=-=-=-=-=-==-

---

!!!Msg erro!!!
statusCode":400,"message":"Unexpected token \r in JSON at position 1240","error":"Bad Request

-=-=-=-=-=-=-==-=--=-=formatter json NOT WORK -==--=-=-=
{"query":"mutation submitCommand($params: SubmitCommandInput!) {\n submitCommand(params: $params) {\n object {\n command {\n id\n address\n city\n corporationName\n country\n source\n discountAmount\n discountId\n eligibleAmount\n email\n firstName\n isCorporate\n lastName\n paymentMethod\n postalCode\n productsAmount\n region\n tipAmount\n totalAmount\n createdAtUtc\n eTicketUrl\n currency\n extraDonation\n formId\n formLang\n formType\n locale\n organizationCountry\n status\n transactions {\n id\n __typename\n }\n __typename\n }\n nextAction {\n type\n redirectToUrl {\n returnUrl\n url\n __typename\n }\n paymentIntentSecret\n __typename\n }\n __typename\n }\n error {\n code\n message\n data {\n fullRates {\n id\n remainingTickets\n __typename\n }\n fullChoices {\n id\n remainingAnswers\n __typename\n }\n remainingTicketingSeats\n __typename\n }\n __typename\n }\n __typename\n }\n}\n"}

ERRO {"statusCode":400,"message":"Unexpected end of JSON input","error":"Bad Request"}

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.